# Differentiating $f(z)=az^2+b\bar zz+c\bar z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f(z)=az^2+b\bar zz+c\bar z^2,$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb C$ are fixed. By differentiating $f(z)$, show that f is complex differentiable at $z$ if and only if $bz+2c\bar z=0.$

So far I've tried the following:
$$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{a(z+\Delta z)^2+b(z+\Delta z)(\overline {z+\Delta z})+c(\overline {z+\Delta z})^2-az^2-bz\bar z-c\bar z^2}{\Delta z}$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{az^2+2az\Delta z+a\Delta z^2+bz\bar z+bz\overline {\Delta z}+b\Delta z\bar z+b\Delta z\overline{\Delta z}+c\bar z^2+2c\bar z\overline {\Delta z}+c\overline{\Delta z}^2-az^2-bz\bar z-c\bar z^2}{\Delta z}$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{2az\Delta z+a\Delta z^2+bz\overline {\Delta z}+b\Delta z\bar z+b\Delta z\overline{\Delta z}+2c\bar z\overline {\Delta z}+c\overline{\Delta z}^2}{\Delta z}$$
$$=2az+b\bar z+\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} b\overline {\Delta z}+\overline {\Delta z}\frac {(bz+2c\bar z+c\overline {\Delta z})}{\Delta z}$$

If the terms $b\bar z, b\overline {\Delta z},$ and $c\overline {\Delta z}^2/\Delta z$ weren't there, this would be easy... I'm not sure how to eliminate these terms. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you already met the Wirtinger derivatives? It's much easier with them.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we've only discussed the definition of complex derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're practically there. In

$$2az+b\bar z+\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} b\overline {\Delta z}+\overline {\Delta z}\frac {(bz+2c\bar z+c\overline {\Delta z})}{\Delta z},$$

everything that had two $\Delta$ factors in the numerator tends to $0$, just collect the terms according to their order:

$$\underbrace{2az + b\overline{z}}_{\text{constant}} + \underbrace{b\overline{\Delta z} + c \frac{\overline{\Delta z}^2}{\Delta z}}_{\to 0} + \underbrace{\frac{\overline{\Delta z}}{\Delta z}(bz + 2c\overline{z})}_{\text{this is the critical part}}.$$

The quotient $\frac{\overline{\Delta z}}{\Delta z}$ has modulus $1$, but can attain any value in the unit circle. Thus the limit exists if and only if the factor it is multiplied with is zero.

Comment: I didn't realize (delta z bar) approached zero as delta z did. The circle argument is what I planned on using once I got rid of the bad terms, but I still don't understand why (delta z bar)^2/(delta z) approaches zero as (delta z) does.

Comment: $\overline{\Delta z}$ is the conjugate of $\Delta z$. Therefore $\lvert \overline{\Delta z}\rvert = \lvert \Delta z\rvert$, and $$\left\lvert \frac{\overline{\Delta z}^2}{\Delta z}\right\rvert = \lvert \Delta z\rvert.$$